# Configure asp.net web-api to use identity server4 access-token

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, identityserver4

I'm trying to figure out how to configure as asp.net web api application to use Identity server4. This is not an asp.net core application. I have examples of how to configure a .net core application from identity server4 quickstarts. How do i configure the OWIN startup.cs to use identity server4 Access-token?

Comment: Can use the IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation package. It worked out of the box afaik.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i found that package. and some other links https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/164

Comment: No problems, you are welcome

Comment: Looks like if you are doing asp.net webapi andmvc with framework 4.6+ you need to use identityserver3 configuration. see https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html